# Convert HLS stream to fixed FPS mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert an HLS stream to mp4 using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i https://example.com/xxx.m3u8 -y -vcodec copy -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc test.mp4
```

I only have access to this video from the stream, and I need it in mp4 format to send on for processing, but I want to be able to set the FPS of the mp4, so that it is consistent.

The HLS stream looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=264000
xxx/xxx007e.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=464000
xxx/xxx0080.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=768000
xxx/xxx0082.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1200000
xxx/xxx0084.m3u8
```

Comment: Is re-encoding ok? Why do you believe the stream is variable FPS? That is a master playlist with entries for variants. They don't represent differing framerates.

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-r 30` to designate 30 fps for your mp4 output. 
The whole cmd can be like this

`ffmpeg -i https://example.com/xxx.m3u8 -y -vcodec copy -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc test.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i https://example.com/xxx.m3u8 -map 0 -vcodec copy -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc test.mp4
```

See the new options:

1. **-map 0** maps all streams from the input.
2. **-re** reads in the live stream HLS at its' rate. Not specifying this may result in FFmpeg hanging (as it waits for referenced packets that are not in the manifest).

It would be more useful if you could provide stream details, such as running [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) or [ffprobe](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) against the master manifest. That way we can recommend encoding settings to use.